# summing table column based on onkeyup element of the table TD

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a onkeyup method to update each row label automatically. At the end of the table there is a label markup that updates the sum automatically. I am having problem updating the final label as the sum of the column,

Here is my code

```
<table class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="paymentTable">
  <thead>
    <th style="width: 1%;">NO</th>
    <th style="width: 30%;">MATA UANG</th>
    <th>RATE</th>
    <th>SETORAN</th>
     <th>TOTAL IDR</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td style='width: 1%; '>$row[curr_id]</td>";
      echo "<td>$row[curr_code] - $row[curr_desc]</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$row[conv_rate]' id='convRate$i'>$row[conv_rate]</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text' onkeyup='processCurr($i);' id='inputCurr$i'/></td>";
      echo "<td><label id='calculatedCurr$i' class='calculatedCurr'></label></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $i++;
    }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table><br/>
TOTAL = <label id='totalSumPayment'></label>
```

and my javascript,

```
<script>
    $('#paymentTable').dataTable();
    function processCurr(param){    
        var inputcurr= $('#inputCurr'+param).val();
        var conversion = $('#convRate'+param).val();
        $('#calculatedCurr'+param).html(inputcurr * conversion);
        calculateSum();
    }

    function calculateSum(){
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".calculatedCurr").each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
//                $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
            }
            else if (this.value.length != 0){
//                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });

    $("#totalSumPayment").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

My problem is, the calculateSum() doesn't work as expected since no value is showing up on the `<label>`. And I'm getting error = TypeError: this.value is undefined on the firebug. Please help me....

Comment: Here  elements with class calculatedCurr are not text boxes.So this.value will not get you the correct value.The correct value is in inner html of .calculatedCurr elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not pointing to a specific element. You have to use the parameters in the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

```
      $(".calculatedCurr").each(function(key, value) {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
//                $(key).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        }
        else if (value.length != 0){
//                $(key).css("background-color", "red");
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is given below.

```
//iterate through each textboxes and add the values 
      $(".calculatedCurr").each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
//                $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
            }
            else if (this.value.length != 0){
//                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });
```

Here **.calculatedCurr** elements are not text boxes.They are labels.So **this.value** will not get you the correct value.The correct value is in inner html of **.calculatedCurr** elements.